# Drag child and parent together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a div structure as below.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="innerWrapper">
      <div id="obj"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Currently I'm using jQuery's draggable to move the div around.

```
jQuery('#obj').draggable();
```

Now I'm in a situation where I need to drag `#wrapper` by dragging `#obj`. How can I do this? So basically I want to be able to drag `#obj` and also drag `#wrapper` together.

When I do this

```
jQuery('#wrapper').draggable();
```

It does not respond well on touch devices maybe because `#obj` is overlapping `#wrapper`

Comment: What you mean by "does not respond well", not working at all ? and which "touch devices" are you using ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki It work's only when touched on the edges of `#wrapper`.  Does not work at all when touched in the center of `#wrapper`. I've tried on iPad and iPhone.

Comment: @Patel thanks. Your `#container` position does not change. That's what I need. I need to move the parent while dragging the child.

Comment: @Bekki But the `parent` and `para` both move. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Patel: I'm afraid it does not. See https://jsfiddle.net/YvJhE/596/ I've removed your `containment:`

Comment: @Bekki The only reason your fiddle didn't work is because that you were trying to access it with the HTTPS protocol. Remove the https and it works just fine. Patel's solution was good otherwise.

Comment: @BishopBarber wat do you mean I'm using `HTTPS protocol`?

Comment: All I'm saying is your precedent link contained a HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP, thus why it didn't work. Remove the 's' and the fiddle should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **handle option in the draggable ui** which allow to restrict the parent from getting dragged unless the mousedown occurs on the specified element(s) in the child.

For your code you can do:

`jQuery( "#wrapper" ).draggable({ handle: "div#obj" });`

For code reference : http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/8862/

For library reference: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle